# Encode '\r\n' in HTML text input

Tags: php, html, browser, encoding, newline

The below PHP code prints a string taken from an HTML text input.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="sender">Your text</label>
<input type="text" name="sender" id="sender" class="form-control" placeholder="example" />
</div>

<?php
print $_POST["sender"]." \r\nSecond senetence.";
?>
```

Please note the second `\r\n` in the concatenated string.

[HTML form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lopIb.jpg)

When I enter: `\r\nFirst sentence.` in the HTML text input, the output is:

```
\r\nFirst sentence. Second sentence.
```

Why is the first `\r\n` taken literally and how can I resolve this?

I've tried `'\r\n' "\r\n" \\r\\n` but non seem to work. Also since I want the `\r\n` in the PHP string, `<br />, &#13 and &#10` won't work.

Comment: look at your html source; the line breaks are there alright.

Comment: you also need a form with a post method; that's unknown.

Comment: *"I've tried '\r\n'"* - FYI: That won't parse in single quotes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- The html code I posted is a snippet from a main html form. I can post the whole code if you want.

Comment: @Fred-ii- "I've tried '\r\n'" :everything prints on the screen, including the \r\n.

Comment: @Fred-ii- If I understood ok, the line breaks are not there; he's getting four chars: \, r, \ and n.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas they're doing something wrong. As I stated earlier; if they view their HTML source, they will see (and you will too if you set that up) that the text inputted and the `Second senetence` are in fact one underneath the other. I won't post an answer to prove this. If they want the linebreaks to appear one underneath the other "on screen", they'd have to use `<br>`. Plus, I did test (for the sake of argument) and added their missing form tags and post method. There isn't anything I can add to this.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas there, see saarbaan's comment just above mine. I rest my case ;-)

Comment: @saarbaan I posted my answer below; given the other ones.

Comment: @jotaelesalinas Sorry, I meant you're exactly right. I am getting chars instead of line breaks. I pointed my comment to the wrong person.:)

Comment: @saarbaan I'm confused though. You state that you tried different combinations of `\n\r` yet you say that you can't modify code. I think I'll have to delete my answer and your question is unclear.

Comment: @saarbaan I deleted my answer. Sorry but there isn't anything I can offer you; good luck.

Comment: @saarbaan right on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot change the code, it is more complicated but still possible.

The browser is going to filter/encode/sanitize everything you enter in the text field, so you will have to do something after that step.

My suggestion is:

- use Firefox
- install extension [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/)
- use it to modify the text you send, e.g. inserting `%0D%0A` at the beginning; which is the URL-encoded version of `\r\n`

A little bit cumbersome but doable.

Comment: I am looking at TamperData usage now.

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked liked a charm on the first try.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="*">` doesn't accept newlines.

Use `<textarea rows="1"></textarea>` instead.

Bear in mind that you will have to show your output in a `<pre>` or another `<textarea>` if you want to show the newlines. Other possibility is using PHP's `nl2br()`.

Comment: I cannot change the code, my interaction with the code is through the text input.